# css media queries replace map with embed image

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, google-maps, media-queries

I'm trying to replace a gmap that I have on my index page with an embedded image version for mobile. The map looks okay on desktop but when I view it on mobile it is too long and scrolling to the end of the page is challenging due to the gmap. 
I've set "scrollwheel: false" on the JS which fixed this for desktop but on mobile still does not work. I've also placed the map width to 90% but the map still looks to large on mobile. So I've decided to replace the map with an embedded image version of it once the screen size goes under 767px. The only thing is that I'm not sure how to go about swapping the two (gmap to image). Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Some details about the page, it is being displayed using the RoR's "render".

index.html:

```
<div id="map" class="google-maps">
     <%= render "gmap" %>
</div>
```

_gmap.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({
       provider: {
          scrollwheel: false,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
          maxZoom: 64
       },
       internal: {
          id: 'map'
       }
    }, function() {
       markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw@hash.to_json%>);
       handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
       handler.fitMapToBounds()
    });
    handler
</script>
```

gmap.css

```
.google-maps {  
    width: 90%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the basics...

I would suggest moving up, instead of down. or - just split it...

If you pull in a map... but then replace that with an image... it's a bit backward.  : )

(updated this link...)
http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/lLwgk/

```
$(function() {

  var wWidth = $(window).width();

  if (wWidth > 1200) {

    $('#yo').append('<img alt="big image" src="http://placehold.it/1200x800" />')
    // you can put any code in here... : )

  } else {

    $('#yo').append('<img alt="big image" src="http://placehold.it/600x400" />')

  }

});
```

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/azOyQV

This shows how to use a data-attribute for stuff too - maybe doesn't suit this - but this watches for changes.

Comment: You can get more complex if you want to - and watch for resize.

Comment: Thank you sheriffderek. 
This work great for swaping an image file to another image file. What about a google maps api to an embeded google maps or image file? Can something like that be responsive and swap after the screen's width does under 767px?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your templating engine, but this approach is just an `if / else` statement - so, you can put anything in it you want. Not sure of your map API needs. I would toss that in a function, and append it instead of including it the way you have it. And again, I would say, `if the window is not bigger that 767px, insert the image, otherwise (767 or bigger) - append the map` (i also strongly discourage your targeting of - iPad in specific)